# Binary Tree. Identify element v in T such that k-1 elements in T are smaller than v

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have this problem I need to solve. I am not looking for an answer, but a hint towards where I should go. I have an algorithm, but it is not O(log n).

Given Binary Tree T and a positive integer k that is no greater than the number of nodes in T, write pseudocode that identifies an element v in T such that precisely k − 1 elements in T are smaller than v. Your code should take time at most proportional to the
height of T.

The basic idea I have here is that I would first check the left tree, checking the size of the left tree. If the size of the left tree is greater than k-1, than I continue searching left. Else I would search Right. If the entire left tree does not contain a node with k-1 elements then I search the right subtree. The problem is that I know this isn't O(log n) because worst case I would have to search every node in the tree.

Is there something I am missing? Any hints or help would be awesome, but please don't just give me an answer.

Comment: Look carefully at the tree structure you have, and what guarantees come with it. Do you know how large a subtree is without traversing it? Is everything in the left subtree less than or equal to the value at the current node? Are the values distinct? Do you know something about the height of the subtrees without exploring them? Is the "height of T" actually proportional to "log n"?

Comment: I should mention that each nodes contains a element size, which is the number of nodes rooted at that node. So I can know how large a subtree is by looking at its size element. And everything in the left tree will be less than the value at the current node. The size values will not always be distinct. There can be multiple nodes with size k-1. And as far as I know from what I have learned in my classes the height of the tree is always proportional to log n.

Comment: When you move right at node v, you need to adjust your search value to `k - (1 + size of left child tree of v)`. Other than that you're ok, you can do the descent in O(tree height) since you can make the correct decision at each node with that size counter.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I'm still not understanding. I still feel like it would need to go back up the tree and check for right sub trees for an element with left tree of size k-1. Lets say I work my way all the way down the left sub tree, checking each left sub tree until I reach a null link. Shouldn't I check the right sub trees for  an element with a left sub tree of k-1?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that the tree is in fact a binary *search* tree, and not just any old binary tree)

Your algorithm is `O(d)`, where `d` is the maximum depth of the tree.

This is because every time you do that comparison, you proceed to go down one more level (assuming you haven't found the element yet). Hence, you will be doing at most as many comparisons as there are levels in the tree.

So, unless your tree is *really* unbalanced, you're not actually ever going to look through every element. In fact, if you can assume that the tree is balanced, you're already good to go (why?).

Comment: [The correct algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19066261/1711796) looks similar to the one described in the question, but the one is the question is indeed O(n), not O(d).

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about a regular binary tree, it's fairly easy to prove that you need to explore the entire tree to find such a node, so I'll assume we're talking about a binary search tree.

In a binary search tree, the following are smaller than a node N:

- Node A, its left child and all it's descendants, where node B is the right child of node A and node B is node N or any of its ancestors.

  ```
      A
     / \
    X   B
   /     \
  Y      ...
   \     /
    Z   N
  ```

  A, X, Y and Z are all smaller than N. (by the same rule, B is also smaller than N).
- The left child of node N

I suspect you were assuming just all children are smaller.

****SPOILER ALERT****

**Algorithm:**

Looking for a node where `m` elements are smaller...

1. Start at the top.
2. Let `x` = the number of nodes in the left subtree (x = 0 if there is no left child)
3. If `x = m`, return the current node.
4. If `x < m`, recurse left.
5. If `x > m`, set `m = m - x - 1` and recurse right.

Since you only go either left or right, and the node count is constant (since it's given on a node level), the running time is `O(h)` where `h` is the height of the tree, which is `O(log n)` in a balanced tree.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost the same algorithm as quickselect. Recurse either to the left or right branch depending on the size of the left branch.

```
Find(T, k) :=
    size(T.left) == k - 1 -> return T
    size(T.left) > k - 1 -> return Find(T.left, k)
    size(T.left) < k - 1 -> return Find(T.right, k - size(T.left) - 1)
```

It's not given directly in the question (but *is* clarified in the comments) that size(T) is O(1).

This takes at most height(T) steps, since the height decreases by at least 1 at each recursive step.

You can also write this iteratively:

```
Find(T, k) := 
   while size(T.left) != k - 1:
       if size(T.left) > k - 1:
           T = T.left
       else:
           T = T.right
           k -= size(T.left) + 1
   return T
```